# Storing the correct answer to check against

Tags: mysql, database-design, normalization

I'm designing a database for a polling app. Users get to answer a bunch of questions and we store them.

**The relevant ERD part**
[image]

I want to store the correct answer for each question so we can check whether they answered the question right or not.

The questions can have different "types":

- string
- number
- single_response
- multiple_response

**How should I store the correct answer?**

**Adding `correct_answer` to both `questions` and `options`**

adding just a `correct_answer` field to `questions` wouldn't work in case the `question` has `type` `multiple_reponse`. I've thought about adding `correct_answer` to both `questions` and `options` where `questions` would have a string or number with the correct answer and `options` would simply get a `true` or `false`. We'd check if all `options` with `correct_answer` set to `true` are selected or not and if an `option` with `correct_answer` set to false is selected

**Creating a new table called `correct_answer`**

Add 2 columns:

- `correct_answer`
- `options_id`

And then check if either is set. We'd have to create a new `correct_answer` for each `option`.

**Adding `correct_answer` to `questions`**

We could use `type` to determine how to read `correct_answer` and then either check `correct_answer` directly or `explode()` a comma delimited `option_id` value to check the answer

I'd like to know which option is the best practice or if anyone has a better idea.

My entire sql: [fiddle](http://rextester.com/DCNU79508)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding 2 Columns in Question_Option entity, one as IsCorrectAnswer and HasMultiAnswers ? You can letter check the counts of answers where HasMultiAnswers is set to true.

Comment: Good idea, I'll see if it works for me :D, thanks!